# Babel Decorators: Is it Possible to Create an "@export" Decorator?

Tags: decorator, ecmascript-next, babel-decorator

I'm new to "ES7" decorators (by which I really mean decorators enabled by the Babel `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` plug-in that was originally based on the ES7 decorator proposal), and I'm having a little trouble with how they work.  I understand that a method decorator modifies the method, but I'm unclear what "side effects" can happen in the process.  Specifically I'd like to know if a decorator can generate an `export`, ie. can I make a decorator like this:

```
class Foo {
    @export
    bar() { doSomething(); }
}
```

which generates:

```
export const bar = Foo.prototype.bar;
// or
export const bar = new (Foo()).bar;
```

or alternatively:

```
class Foo {
    @export
    static bar() { doSomething(); }
}
```

to:

```
export const bar = Foo.bar;
```

In short, can a decorator ever create an `export` statement?

Comment: Exports should be declared at the top of a module so that they are statically analysable. So even if you _could_ (it would probably require some hacky plugin for a transpiler, e.g Babel), you really shouldn't.

Comment: Why do you want to export a method at all?

Comment: A module might expose something as if it were a static function, but (behind the scenes) it might make more sense to implement that function as a method of a (singleton) object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, export declarations cannot be created dynamically. At best, you could dynamically create a module file that contains them.